Custom dialog opens on page load, instead of click
I'm trying to develop a modal window for the first time using dialog. The problem is that the dialog window appears as soon as the page is loaded, instead of appearing when I click the selected button. When I click the button, it resizes the one that appears when the page loads.


"use strict";

const openBtn = document.querySelector(".open_btn");
const dialog = document.querySelector(".nav_open-account-dialog");
const closeBtn = dialog.querySelector(".close_btn");

openBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #17152a;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22rem;
}

@keyframes moveCircle {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(2vw);
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vw;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: moveCircle 3s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}

.circle.two {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle.three {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18vw;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle.four {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28vw;
  left: 74%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle.five {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35vw;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 9.6rem;
  margin-right: 9.6rem;
}

.nav_logo .first-letter {
  font-size: 4.4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #0595ec;
}

.nav_logo .rest-letter {
  font-size: 4.4rem;
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.nav_btns a {
  margin-right: 4.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.nav_btns a:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #0595ec;
  color: #0595ec;
}

.nav_open-account button {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  width: 12.8rem;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  background-color: #ff7f50;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav_open-account button:hover {
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.4rem;
  /* transform: scale(1.05); */
  background-color: #0595ec;
}

.nav_btns a {
  margin-right: 4.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 12.8rem;
  margin-left: 9.6rem;
  margin-right: 9.6rem;
  gap: 8rem;
}

.header_description {
  flex: 1;
}

.header_form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0.3rem solid #f8f9fa;
  padding: 8rem;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  gap: 2.4rem;
}

.header_one {
  color: #0595ec;
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header_two {
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 4.8rem;
}

.header_three {
  color: #0595ec;
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  padding-left: 9.6rem;
}

.header_description p {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.login_header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #0595ec;
  width: 9.6rem;
  height: 4.8rem;
  border-radius: 0 0 1.2rem 1.2rem;
}

.login_header span {
  color: #f8f9fa;
}

.input_box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

.login_label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0595ec;
  border: 0.2rem solid white;
  border-radius: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0 0;
  height: 2.4rem;
  width: 9.8rem;
  top: -57%;
  left: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.input_field {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #0595ec;
  padding-inline: 1.2rem 2.4rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  outline: none;
}

.input_field:focus {
  border-color: #0595ec;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.input_field:focus,
.input_btn button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.6rem #0595ec;
  border-color: #0595ec;
}

.input_btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4.8rem;
}

.input_btn button {
  padding: 1.4rem 2.6rem;
  background-color: #0595ec;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid #f8f9fa;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input_btn button:hover {
  background-color: #007bb5;
  transform: translateY(-0.2rem);
}


/* Modal window */

.nav_open-account-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog h2 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem 0;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="text"],
.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="tel"],
.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  outline: none;
}

.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="text"]:focus,
.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="tel"]:focus,
.nav_open-account-dialog input[type="email"]:focus {
  border-color: #007bff;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
}

.modal_btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.modal_btn:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
  transform: translateY(-0.2rem);
}

.close_btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
}

.close_btn:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
  transform: translateY(-0.2rem);
}
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle two"></div>
  <div class="circle three"></div>
  <div class="circle four"></div>
  <div class="circle five"></div>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="nav_logo">
        <span class="nav_logo first-letter">B</span
            ><span class="nav_logo rest-letter">ank!fy</span
            ><span class="nav_logo first-letter">.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_btns">
        <a href="#about_us">About Us</a>
        <a href="#our_app">Our App</a>
        <a href="#our_team">Team</a>
        <a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_open-account">
        <button class="open_btn">Join Us</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="header_description">
      <h1 class="header_one">Secure.</h1>
      <h2 class="header_two">Simple.</h2>
      <h3 class="header_three">Smart.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="header_form">
      <div class="login_header">
        <span>Login</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input_box">
        <input type="text" id="user" class="input_field" required />
        <label for="user" class="login_label">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input_box">
        <input type="password" id="pass" class="input_field" required />
        <label for="pass" class="login_label">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input_btn">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <dialog class="nav_open-account-dialog">
    <h2>Join Us</h2>
    <p>Welcome! Please sign up to become a member.</p>

    <form action="#" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
      </div>

      <button class="modal_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>

      <button class="close_btn" type="close">Close</button>
    </form>
  </dialog>
</div>




I'd hazard a guess that it's because you have applied the position: absolute and z-index: 10 rules to the dialog, causing it to always be displayed on top of everything, no matter what. Try commenting out all the styling rules you've applied to the dialog box and let the default HTML styling rules show/hide the dialog

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

@AustinDuling had a good hunch with the CSS; I would look at the display:flex there.

This is because your form in the dialog box should be like this: <form method="dialog">

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Thank you very much to everyone for the help! The issue was indeed as @mykaf mentioned with display: flex. Additionally, both position: absolute and z-index were unnecessary, but even after removing them, the problem still persisted, and the dialog window was still appearing. After removing flex, it was fixed, and the window only appears when the Join button is clicked. Thank you, and I apologize for my post, which wasn't the most efficient. This is my first post here, and I'm a novice both in using this site and in web development, as this is my first project.
